# Tomcat - Custom Session Cookie Handling

Tags: java, session, tomcat

my issue is as follows: We are working on deploying our application as a WebApp inside Tomcat. However, our software is capable of running in a multi-tenancy mode, i.e. have multiple "clients" (tenants) served by one instance of the WebApp.

The URLs would look like this (let's assume the WebApp's context is `/app`:

- For the client Customer 1, the data would be served for URLs `/app/customer1/<path>`
- For the client Customer 2, the data would be server for URLs `/app/customer2/<path>`

So far, everything works as expected - apart from Session Management. We would like to use two *distinct* **Session Cookies** for the two different paths `/app/customer1` and `/app/customer2`. However, the issue is that Tomcat *always* creates a **Session Cookie** for the WebApp's context path `/app` which cannot be changed afterwards.

Does anyone know a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance!

Michael

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to create two separate url patterns for the application.

Using @WebServlet:

```
@WebServlet(
    urlPatterns={"/app/customer1/servlet", "/app/customer2/servlet"})
```

Or, using web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>myPackage.myClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/customer1/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyApp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/app/customer2/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Now, when you create a cookie, the path will default to the one that accessed the servlet. Each customer will only get its cookie.

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("color", "green");
```

---

Here is a servlet showing and creating the cookies.

```
@WebServlet(
    urlPatterns={"/app/customer1/servlet", "/app/customer2/servlet"})
public class CookieExample extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
          throws ServletException, IOException {
        String urlSaved = "No Saved URL";
        Cookie[] cookies = req.getCookies();
        for (Cookie aCookie : cookies) {
            if ("url".equals(aCookie.getName())) {
                urlSaved = aCookie.getValue();
            }
        }
        resp.getWriter().print("Saved url = " + urlSaved); 
        String path = req.getRequestURI().substring(
            req.getRequestURI().indexOf("/app")
        );
        resp.addCookie(new Cookie("url", path));
    }    

}
```

Here is an image showing that two cookies named 'url' have been created. The details of one of them are shown. The path is for one customer, the content has the path to the specific customer and it is a session cookie. The other one is similar, except the path is for the other customer.

[image: List of cookies showing two cookies]

The way I generated the cookies depends on how the app is accessed. I used two different links:

```
    <a href="app/customer1/servlet">Cookie Customer 1</a><br>
    <a href="app/customer2/servlet">Cookie Customer 2</a>
```

Comment: The issue is, the Session Cookie created by Tomcat does not respect this, it always gets created with the app's context as path (i.e. `/app`). I would like for the *Session Cookie* set by Tomcat to behave as you described.